# golang interface "used as value" error

Tags: go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type animal interface {
    speak()
}

type dog struct {
    name, sound  string
}

type cat struct {
    name, sound  string
}

func (d dog) speak() {
    fmt.Println(d.name, " goes ", d.sound)
}

func (c cat) speak() {
    fmt.Println(c.name, " goes ", c.sound)
}

func animal_speak(a animal) {
    fmt.Println(a.speak())
}

func main() {

    dogo := dog{"scooby", "woof"}
    cato := cat{"garfield", "meow"}

    animal_speak(dogo)
    animal_speak(cato)

}
```

When I call the animal interface it gives me the following error

> ./interface.go:28:21: a.speak() used as value

What am I doing wrong?

[Link to playground](https://play.golang.org/p/HzVzgC7u2cU)

Comment: as pointed out below, `speak` has no return value, so it can't pass anything to `fmt.Println`. Not directly related, but still worth pointing out: function names in golang are camelCased (or CamelCased for exported ones). The function `animal_speak` would be flagged up in code-review and should be changed to `AnimalSpeak`

Comment: Or `animalSpeak` if it doesn't need to be exported!

Answer (score 7):

The interface is not used as a value.  You're using a function call that returns nothing as a value.

`speak()` returns nothing... so what do you expect it to print?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are printing the output of speak method, your speak method needs to return a string or an object whose string representation would print a string you would like to see. Here's your program modified https://play.golang.org/p/VDsp0cjXBd- to return a string.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on all above answers,
Modified below function

**Before**

```
   func animal_speak(a animal) {
        fmt.Println(a.speak())
    }
```

**After**

```
func animal_speak(a animal) {
    a.speak()
}
```

[Playgorund Link](https://play.golang.org/p/TbkGVjzpZZE)